# Creating a graph using maple

Tags: maple

What is the (maple) code for the following graph: The vertices are the elements of `M_2(\mathbb{Z}_2)` and two vertices `A` and `B` are adjacent if and only if `AB = I`.

If you know the code or any references, please let me know.

Comment: Thank you for the puzzle. My feeling about StackOverflow is that questions are meant to be more focused than, "would you show me the code for this?" Would you show what you have tried, and make the question about why it isn't working? Or make it a question about how to approach the problem yourself, asking for some pointers to get started?

Comment: @DouglasLovell I am new here with a simple question concerning maple programming. So I am sorry for any inconvenience.

Comment: @Sara, I can do this partially. i.e. I can generate all matrix that are invertible with entries in $\Bbb Z_2$. But when I want to define a set with elements of $A$ and $A^{-1}$ (for drawing edge), my code don't work. can you resolve this?

Answer (score 1):

Start step by step. Think what you need. You need to define your set of vertices and then set of edges. First with the set of vertices. You want all matrices of size 2 by 2 with binary entries, it means a finite set of 16 elements. Matrices are defined in Maple. You can define a matrix with entries (1,1), (1,2), (2,1) and (2,2) beign a, b, c and d respectively in one of the following two ways.

```
M := Matrix([ [a, b], [c, d] ]);
```

which means row-wise, or column-wise as in below.

```
M := < < a, b > | < c, d > >;
```

Now, I want to put them in an ordered collection, so I choose list data structure. You can make an empty list and then add the matrices one by one with for-loops to it, but since lists are immutable data structures, I would use `Array` instead and then convert it to a list in the end. Another way is to use list-comprehension using `seq`. Here is how I do it.

```
V := [ seq( seq( seq( seq( Matrix([ [a, b], [c, d] ]), d = 0..1 ), c = 0..1 ), b = 0..1 ), a = 0..1 ) ];
```

And you will see a beautiful list with all 16 matrices that you expect.

Now for the set of edges. Your set is small, so going for a command to find the inverse is not really necessary, just have a nested for-loop to actually multiply matrices A and B and then compare if the result is the identity matrix or not. Remember that in Maple `=` is not a mathematical equality comparison. To check whether two matrices are equal, use the `Equal` command in the `LinearAlgebra` package. So here is how I do it.

```
E := Array([]); # empty 1-dimensional array
for A in V do
 for B in V do
  if LinearAlgebra:-Equal( ( A . B mod 2 ) , Matrix([ [1, 0], [0, 1] ]) ) then
   ArrayTools:-Append( E, [A, B] ): # modifying E itself instead of defining new one.
  end if:
 end do:
end do:
```

Now if you ask to see E, you will see 6 ordered pairs of matrices that their product is the the identity matrix. Note the use of `mod` to have remain in GF(2) (binary field). If you do the multiplications and additions in Z and then take mod 2, the result will be the same as if you were doing the multiplications and additions in GF(2) from the beginning.

Technically you already have your graph and if you don't want to do anything further, that is the end. The ordered pair (V, E) is the graph itself. But Maple has a package dedicated to Graph theory called `GraphTheory`. If you want to have a `Graph` object that you can apply the commands of this package on it, then you need to convert the array of edges to a set. Remember that having the edges stored as ordered pairs (list of length 2) will tell Maple that your edges are directed. If you want undirected edges, then use set of length 2. The following line define the graph object for this example.

```
E := convert( E, set );
G := GraphTheory:-Graph( V, E );
```

However, you will get an error message. That is because the elements in your vertices set must be integers or strings or something else, but not matrices, it seems the developers didn't support matrices as label of vertices or something like that. So now instead of saving nodes of the graph as matrices, I pick up the integer indices of them as members of V. For example the identity matrix is the 10th element of V (if you have used the same loop code that I used to generate V above). So instead of asking Maple to have `[1 0\\ 0 1]` as a vertex of G, I will ask it to have `10` as this vertec, and the edge connecting this node to itself, will be `[10, 10]`. So I redefine E and V for G.

```
E := Array([]);
for i from 1 by 1 to 16 do
 for j from 1 by 1 to 16 do
  if LinearAlgebra:-Equal( ( V[i] . V[j] mod 2 ) , Matrix([ [1, 0], [0, 1] ]) ) then
   ArrayTools:-Append( E, [i, j] ):
  end if:
 end do:
end do:
E := convert( E, set );
G := GraphTheory:-Graph( [ seq(i, i = 1..16) ], E );
```

No error message this time :)

Now what can we do with this G? The first thing you may want to try is to draw it. Here is how you can do it using `GraphTheory`'s predefined commands.

```
GraphTheory:-DrawGraph( G );
```

Here is the picture you get from Maple.
[image]

Note that in this case direction was not very important as every edge is two-sided, but in general matrix-multiplication is not commutative so in a different case (if your edge definition is different) you may want to keep the direction and also that is why I did not simplify the nested-loops for E to a n(n-1)/2 cases and kept the whole n^2 cases.